# Copying text from Word to Excel while keeping the formatting (using .typetext)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy question and response data from an excel spreadsheet into a word document. I have a macro that is able to bring across all the text by using the .typetext instruction however - this results in superscript and subscript text being brought over as standard text.

Here is a sample spreadsheet I am using:
[image: Spreadsheet Example]

You can see below that the superscript text has been converted to normal text when copied to the Word document:

[image: Word Export]

Here is my VBA Macro:

```
Sub CopyFromExcelToWord()

    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim myIndex As Integer
    Dim questionNumber As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' this figures out the last used row by counting backwards (up) from the bottom until it finds some data
    questionNumber = 1
   
     ' create a new word application and word document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add ' create a new document
        
    ' insert the question and response data
    For myIndex = 2 To lastRow
        With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection
            .TypeText questionNumber & ". " & Range("A" & myIndex).Value    ' insert the question number and question text
            .TypeParagraph  ' insert a new paragraph ready for the responses
            
            .TypeText "a) " & Range("B" & myIndex).Value & Chr(11)  ' insert the first response data and goto a new line
            .TypeText "b) " & Range("C" & myIndex).Value & Chr(11)  ' insert the second response data and goto a new line
            .TypeText "c) " & Range("D" & myIndex).Value & Chr(11)  ' insert the third response data and goto a new line
            .TypeParagraph
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Save the word document into the WordExport Folder
    wrdDoc.SaveAs "c:\Data\testDocument.docx", FileFormat:=12 'wdFormatXMLDocument
    wrdDoc.Close ' close the document
    
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can someone please offer some tips with how I can get this macro to bring across the superscript and subscript text correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *cannot* preserve character formatting when using .TypeText; you'd need to employ copy/paste for that.

Comment: Thank you @macropod.

I have just now been experimenting with copying and pasting the information across like so:

'.TypeText questionNumber & ". "
Range("A" & myIndex).Copy
.Paste'

However it runs for a while and then gives me this error:

**Run-time error '4605'

This method or property is not available because the clipboard is empty or not valid.**